# Is that considered as "keyword stuffing"

Tags: seo, keywords, keyword-stuffing

I manage a website, and one of the pages lists all musical events around a city. I would like to explain that the events cover all musical styles, but I don't know if it is considered as keyword stuffing. The paragraph for now looks like this (translated from French).

"[...]All musical style : from pop to rock, not forgetting rap, reggae, soul and metal !"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider coming up with a phrase a user would search for ie: **Find Local Musical Events in City/State | Times, Dates and Ticket Info**

Then let each event's title and description do the rest. I think if it doesn't feel right, most likely it's not right.

> Is that considered as “keyword stuffing”

No. But could it be more well thought out? You decide.

**Note:** I don't mean that offensively by any means.

Comment: thanks a lot ! Oh and my website has other pages thats describes other type of events (like "expos", "Theaters"...) and the description (not in the meta but at the top of the page) begin the same way "My website presents you "stuff"). My coworker says it is duplicate content, is that so ?

Comment: I suggest using the same method, replace Musical with Theaters etc.. As long as it really has to do with your content, you will not by any means get dinged nor will it ever be considered duplicate. If you as the user knows the difference and see it as clearly different and useful content, so will the search bots. :)